# Error while querying database

Tags: php, mysql

I started to learn PHP and MySql from Head First and now i'm in chapter 2 and i'm doing some exercises from book.

```
    $connection = mysql_connect("127.0.0.1", "root", "", "aliendatabase")
or die ("Oops! Couldn't connect to server because ". mysql_error());



    $sql="INSERT INTO aliens_abduction (first_name, last_name, when_it_happened, how_long, how_many, alien_description, what_they_did, fang_spotted, other, email)
    VALUES ('$first_name', '$last_name', '$when_it_happened', '$how_long', 'how_many', '$alien_description', '$what_they_did', '$fang_spotted', '$other', '$email')";


    mysqli_query($connection, $sql)
    or die('Error querying database.' . mysql_error());

  mysqli_close($connection);
```

While i was writing that part, i keep getting "Error querying database" error. Can anyone show me what's wrong in this code?

Comment: "Error querying database" should be followed by the mysql_error(). What is the error?

Comment: It doesn't say anything just "Error querying database.".

Comment: @user3559801 You're mixing mysqli and mysql. You can't youse these both at te same time ;) I suggest you to use MYSQLI :)

Comment: @Callie are there any important difference between mysql and mysqli? :)

Comment: @user3559801 Well, msqli is just a newer library/version with more functionallity especially for Object Oriented Programming. The 'i' stands for improved.Here you can find a list of the improvements. [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.overview.php)

Comment: @user3559801 No problem man! That's why we're all here, to learn every day more and more ;)

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to sql injection (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).  You might want to consider using prepared statements with mysqli or PDO (PDO is newer).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cant use mysqli_query after starting with mysql_query.

```
<?php

$connection = mysql_connect("127.0.0.1", "root", "", "test") or die ("Oops! Couldn't connect to server because ". mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("test");


$sql="INSERT INTO users (id) VALUES (100000)";


mysql_query($sql,$connection) or die('Error querying database.' . mysql_error());

mysql_close($connection);
```

Here is a tutorial for ***Mysqli***: [Link](http://codular.com/php-mysqli)

For this purpose here is the mysqli code:

```
$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'aliendatabase');

if($db->connect_errno > 0){
    die('Unable to connect to database [' . $db->connect_error . ']');
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO aliens_abduction (first_name, last_name, when_it_happened, how_long, how_many, alien_description, what_they_did, fang_spotted, other, email)
VALUES ('$first_name', '$last_name', '$when_it_happened', '$how_long', 'how_many', '$alien_description', '$what_they_did', '$fang_spotted', '$other', '$email')";

if(!$result = $db->query($sql)){
    die('There was an error running the query [' . $db->error . ']');
}

$db->close();
```

Comment: So should i change mysql_connect() to mysqli_connect()?

Comment: If you know how to use Myslqi yes... But it seems like you don't. I added a tutorial for it ;)

Comment: I'll try to figure it out somehow. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing `mysqli` (note the **(i)**) and `mysql` (note the LACK of an (i)). The two libraries are NOT interchangeable/mixable like that. Connections established in one are NOT usable by the other.

Note the differences in your calls:

```
mysql_connect()
mysqli_query()
mysql_error()
mysqli_close()
```

Comment: I already told that...

Comment: @OzanKurt: Yes, and? So I should obsessively reload the site just in case someone answered a few seconds before I hit the submit button?

Answer (score 0):

For this purpose here is the mysqli code:

```
$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'aliendatabase');

if($db->connect_errno > 0){
    die('Unable to connect to database [' . $db->connect_error . ']');
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO aliens_abduction (first_name, last_name, when_it_happened, how_long, how_many, alien_description, what_they_did, fang_spotted, other, email)
VALUES ('$first_name', '$last_name', '$when_it_happened', '$how_long', 'how_many', '$alien_description', '$what_they_did', '$fang_spotted', '$other', '$email')";

if(!$result = $db->query($sql)){
    die('There was an error running the query [' . $db->error . ']');
}

$db->close();
```

Comment: now i'm getting "[The server requested authentication method unknown to the client]" error. Is there any way to fix this error?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/385378/mysql-connect-the-server-requested-authentication-method-unknown-to-the-clien  hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be using mysql. The reasons are explained in this article. http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php
Also, you can't mix mysqli with mysql. Here is a brief solution unsing mysqli

```
$connection = new mysqli("127.0.0.1", "root", "", "test") 


$sql="INSERT INTO users (id) VALUES (100000)";


if(mysqli_query($sql,$connection))
{
   //message  if everything goes right
}
else
{
   printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($connection)); //will print the errors
}
```